# Making a combine passthrough publisher less global

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

Swift 5, iOS 13

I want to use passthroughSubject publisher; but I my gut tells me its a global variable and as such very poor practice. How can make this global variable less global, while still being usable. Here's some code to show what I talking about.

I know there are a dozen other ways to do this, but I wanted to create some simple code to illustrate the issue.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

let switcher = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()

struct SwiftUIViewF: View {
@State var nextPage = false
var body: some View {

  VStack {
    Text("Switcher")
    .onReceive(switcher) { (_) in
      self.nextPage.toggle()
    }
    if nextPage {
      Page1ViewF()
    } else {
      Page2ViewF()
    }
  }

 }
}

struct Page1ViewF: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Page 1")
    .onTapGesture {
        switcher.send()
    }
  }
}

struct Page2ViewF: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Page 2")
    .onTapGesture {
      switcher.send()
    }
  }
}

struct SwiftUIViewF_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    SwiftUIViewF()
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your question specific to SwiftUI? It seems you have a very generic problem of not knowing how to correctly create a variable with a scope that all types/instances that need access to it can access it. Why do you think you need a global variable in the first place? What scope of your codebase should be able to access said variable?

Comment: Thenscope is any of the views, although in this example just the ones shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible solution - to hold it in parent and inject into child views:

```
struct SwiftUIViewF: View {
let switcher = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()

@State var nextPage = false
var body: some View {

  VStack {
    Text("Switcher")
    .onReceive(switcher) { (_) in
      self.nextPage.toggle()
    }
    if nextPage {
      Page1ViewF(switcher: switcher)
    } else {
      Page2ViewF(switcher: switcher)
    }
  }

 }
}

struct Page1ViewF: View {
  let switcher: PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>
  var body: some View {
    Text("Page 1")
    .onTapGesture {
        self.switcher.send()
    }
  }
}

struct Page2ViewF: View {
  let switcher: PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>
  var body: some View {
    Text("Page 2")
    .onTapGesture {
      self.switcher.send()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, its so obvious I been looking at this too closely all day.

Comment: I think a better way is to use `@EnvironmentObject`

Answer (score 1):

An example using `@EnvironmentObject`.

Let SDK take care of observing / passing things for you, rather than setting up yourself.

Especially when your usage is a simple toggle.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class EnvState: ObservableObject { @Published var nextPage = false }
 
struct SwiftUIViewF: View {
@EnvironmentObject var env: EnvState
var body: some View {

  VStack {
    Text("Switcher")
    if env.nextPage {
      Page1ViewF()
    } else {
      Page2ViewF()
    }
  }

 }
}

struct Page1ViewF: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var env: EnvState
  var body: some View {
    Text("Page 1")
    .onTapGesture {
        env.nextPage.toggle()
    }
  }
}

struct Page2ViewF: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var env: EnvState
  var body: some View {
    Text("Page 2")
    .onTapGesture {
      env.nextPage.toggle()
    }
  }
}

struct SwiftUIViewF_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    SwiftUIViewF().environmentObject(EnvState())
  }
}
```